# Should I throw subtype of an Exception in the throws clause?

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea

I am writing an API

```
void doSomething(args) throws Exception1, Exception2;
```

Exception1 is a subtype of Exception2.

Intellij idea is saying "There is a more general exception in the throws list already." I know java only requires me to have Exception2 in the throws clause but think I should have both in the throws clause for documentation purposes and to indicate to the caller that they can catch each one separately and do something different for each one. In my implementation of the API, I throw Exception1  and also calling an internal method which throws Exception2.

What is the recommended practice?

Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask why one exception extends from the other?

Comment: I understand that, buy I don't see why you would need to have an Exception hierarchy instead of both extending `Exception`

Comment: Does your method actually throw both exceptions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should write a javadoc that explains the conditions when each particular exception is thrown. Take a look at [ReadableByteChannel.read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html#read%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) javadoc for example - the method declares only IOException in its throws clause, but describes a lot of more specific subclasses of that exception in its javadoc.

Answer (score 5):

Just write `throws Exception2` in your `throws` clause.  The caller can still catch each of them individually, provided they put `catch (Exception1 e)` before `catch (Exception2 e)`.

For example, `FileNotFoundException` is a subtype of `IOException`, and it is valid to write

```
try {
    doSomeStuff();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("There's no such file");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Your IO doesn't work");
}
```

even if `doSomeStuff()` is only declared as throwing `IOException`.  But you can't do it the other way around.  It's invalid to have the superclass's `catch` clause before the subclass's one.

Answer (score 0):

Catch can be more specific than what was nominally thrown, so there's no requirement to explicitly say that you're throwing both if one extends the other. No harm done in doing so either. There MAY be harm done in making one extend the other at all...